# Using a fixed number of elements with jCarousel and dynamically adding and removing beginning and end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently attempting to use jCarousel for a web application, where I display a set of data, one pane at a time, in a vertical carousel. I'm running into an issue where I could have an unknown number of panes created for the data I'll be showing.

Instead of overloading the DOM with tons of lis and their associated content, I'm looking for a way to use jCarousel by creating 3 li elements (I specify 3 because I'll need at least one element above and below the current element being viewed for scrolling purposes), and then dynamically creating a new li at the end when the user clicks "next" at number 2, and at the same time removing the first li. Obviously this would need to support moving forward through all the carousel items, and also back, all the way back to the first.

Hopefully this explanation is clear enough - wish I could draw a picture!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

jCarousel offers many options for dynamically loading content already. For instance you could define a [javascript array of your slides](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_javascript.html):

```
var mycarousel_itemList = [
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg", title: "Flower1"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg", title: "Flower2"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg", title: "Flower3"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg", title: "Flower4"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg", title: "Flower5"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg", title: "Flower6"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg", title: "Flower7"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg", title: "Flower8"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg", title: "Flower9"},
    {url: "http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg", title: "Flower10"}
];

function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{
    for (var i = carousel.first; i <= carousel.last; i++) {
        if (carousel.has(i)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i > mycarousel_itemList.length) {
            break;
        }

        carousel.add(i, mycarousel_getItemHTML(mycarousel_itemList[i-1]));
    }
};
/**
 * Item html creation helper.
 */
function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item)
{
    return '<img src="' + item.url + '" width="75" height="75" alt="' + item.url + '" />';
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
        itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}
    });
});
```

The only html this requires is:

```
  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-ie7">
    <!-- The content will be dynamically loaded in here -->
  </ul>
```